# Configure access role for IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

I have a S3 java client which I want to run. But I get error during startup:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AWSSecurityTokenServiceException: User: arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/test-key is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/test-key (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 3b9b4bd4-48d1-40dc-a7d-f33d1cfffbb5; Proxy: null)
```

Do you know how I can set this permission into AWS IAM panel?

EDIT:

```
    AssumeRoleRequest assumeRequest = (new AssumeRoleRequest()).withRoleArn(awsArn).withDurationSeconds(s3Properties.getSessionDuration()).withRoleSessionName(s3Properties.getAwsSessionname());
    AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = (AWSSecurityTokenService)((AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder)((AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder)AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))).withRegion(s3Properties.getAwsRegion())).build();
    AssumeRoleResult assumeResult = stsClient.assumeRole(assumeRequest);
    Credentials credentials2 = assumeResult.getCredentials();
```

Comment: In the real error message is it really a user for both ARNs? You can't assume role to a user, only a role.

Comment: I'm not sure. Any idea what I need to fix?

Comment: Can you show the relevant code where you initiate the aws client?

Comment: It simply means you test user doesn't have permission. You have to grant permission/policy.

Comment: Can you guide me how to configure this, please?

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that you are using an IAM user to assume an IAM user:

```
User: arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/test-key is not authorized to perform: 
sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/test-key
```

`AssumeRole` is used with IAM *roles*, not IAM *users*. In your code snippet:

```
AssumeRoleRequest assumeRequest = (new AssumeRoleRequest()).withRoleArn(awsArn).withDurationSeconds(s3Properties.getSessionDuration()).withRoleSessionName(s3Properties.getAwsSessionname());
```

The value for `awsArn` must be an IAM user. The value should instead be an IAM role that has a trust policy allowing the `test-key` user to assume the role. Read [the documentation on AssumeRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) and see the example in [the AWS SDK docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/sts_example_sts_AssumeRole_section.html). I won't reproduce them here as they are quite explicit about what you need to do.

Comment: Can you guide me from where I can get this value?

Comment: @PeterPenzov As suggested in the answer, see [the AWS SDK docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/sts_example_sts_AssumeRole_section.html), where you can find a Java example. And if this example make little sense to you, you should learn and play around with IAM first; see [what is an IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id.html#id_iam-roles) and [how to create an IAM role for user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user.html) for starters. In AWS, you can hardly get around without Identity and Access Management...

Comment: I created IAM user with credentials. Can you guide where from AWS panel I have to get this value?

Comment: Here is [the link of an IAM console for roles](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/roles). Create an appropriate role, then put its ARN into `awsArn`. That'll do.

Comment: What needs to be the role that I need to add to the user?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use Assume role with the `roles`, not with the `iam user`

Role ARN Sample - `RoleArn=arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/demo`

SDK Guide - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/sts_example_sts_AssumeRole_section.html

Comment: Can you guide me how I have to configure the value `role/demo` and where from AWS panel I have to get this value?

Comment: I think you are not well versed with AWS IAM, In that scenario please visit IAM WhitePapers to learn about IAM's since Assume role is an advanced concept of IAM.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html

Since you asked for AWS Panel where you can get the value of ARN, Login to your AWS Console > IAM > Roles and there you might be able to locate the value.

Answer (score 0):

You could fix the permission error by creating a new IAM role in the IAM console with S3 access permissions, than update your Java client code to use the ARN of this new role instead of the user ARN in the AssumeRoleRequest. This allows your client to assume temporary credentials with the necessary S3 access, avoiding the attempt to assume its own identity.

```
AssumeRoleRequest assumeRequest = (new AssumeRoleRequest())
  .withRoleArn("arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/myS3Role")
  .withDurationSeconds(s3Properties.getSessionDuration())
  .withRoleSessionName(s3Properties.getAwsSessionname());
```

(replace with your actual role ARN)